# encodeURIComponent on client and decodeURIComponent on server

Tags: javascript, web, url, uri

could someone criticize me this approach:

I want to send a JSON object in a GET method but the body is not available, so I'm encoded the JSON in the client and decoded in the server, like this:

```
// on client
 let query = {
    subject: subject,
    sources: sources
  }
query = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(query))
console.log(encoded);

// on server
const { query } = url.parse(req.url)
decodedQuery = decodeURIComponent(query)
```

it just works, but people use several libraries like querystring and query-string or manually build the query string.

So why don't do what I'm doing?

Regards

Comment: There's a limit on the size of URLs. This won't work for large JSON if it exceeds the limit.

Comment: Using normal `key=value&key=value&...` syntax is compatible with more platforms, like PHP's built-in `$_GET` variables.

Comment: `query =` should be `encoded =` ?

Comment: Why not use `POST` instead of `GET`?

Comment: Not use POST because semantically I'm requesting info not publishing new one, im curious about, why GET doesnt have a body?